# Jquery each function not working on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written a code that is working on a local server but online it is not working, Following shows the Code.

```js
$(".super").each(function() {
var sup = "First Checkbox,Third Checkbox,Fourth Checkbox";
var array = sup.split(",");

$.each(array, function(i) {
   $("input[type=checkbox][value='" + array[i] + "']").prop('checked', true);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td width="150">
      <label>First Checkbox</label>
    </td>
    <td class="super">
      <input type="checkbox" name="txtSup" value="First Checkbox">
    </td>
    <td width="180">
      <label>Second Checkbox</label>
    </td>
    <td class="super">
      <input type="checkbox" name="txtSup" value="Second Checkbox">
    </td>
    <td width="150">
      <label>Third Checkbox</label>
    </td>
    <td class="super">
      <input type="checkbox" name="txtSup" value="Third Checkbox">
    </td>
    <td width="130">
      <label>Fourth Checkbox</label>
    </td>
    <td class="super">
      <input type="checkbox" name="txtSup" value="Fourth Checkbox">
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The above code shows multiple values are separated by commas and I need to get each value and enable the checkbox but It is working on local xampp but online on the server not working.

Comment: That doesn't look like it would work on wither server

Comment: why? Bro Anything wrong

Comment: Are the jQuery library files presents on your server?

Comment: if you are running the script on server then manage it line by line by consoling it .. there might be many cases that your $(".super") is undefined or null or could not be found in DOM so you will have to debug it line by line

Comment: Selector seems iffy to me: `$("input[type=checkbox 
        [value='"+array[i]+"']")`

Comment: "not working" means what exactly? Do you get an error in your browser's Console? Or some functionality doesn't produce the expected output? Do you understand how to use the Debugger in your browser's Developer Tools to step through your code and check what it's doing? P.S. Since you used the keyword `super` as a variable name, it's hard to see how this has ever worked in any environment (unless you tested with an older browser or something)

Comment: Don't call people "bro" here. This website is not a chat.

Comment: @Tomalak It's not the military either. They weren't exactly offensive; have a day off.

Comment: other things are working but this one not.

Comment: @Samson I edited your snippet to put the HTML inside the HTML section (and not in the JavaScript section, where you had placed it), and now it seems to work ok. Pay more attention to the different boxes in the code editor. It's not quite the same as when you create a web page normally (e.g. using a standard text editor)

Comment: @Samson P.S. There's really no need to replace your original, broken version of the code with the version from the answer. Now your question doesn't make a lot of sense, because there's no longer any evidence of the original problem. We can already see the corrected version below, so you don't need to repeat it. Consider rolling your question back to the version which contained the original non-working code. If you go to [your question's edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56833989/revisions) you should be able to hit the Rollback button to go to one of your earlier versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues in your logic.

- `super` is a reserved keyword in ECMA2015. You will need to rename that variable
- The `type` and `value` attribute selectors need to be separated; ie. add the missing `]`
- You cannot have `div` elements as children of `tr`. Remove them.
- You've repeated the same `txtSup` id attribute when they must be unique. Remove that attribute, you can change it to a `class` if needed.

```js
$(".super").each(function() {
  var sup = "First Checkbox,Third Checkbox,Fourth Checkbox";
  var array = sup.split(",");

  $.each(array, function(i) {
    $("input[type=checkbox][value='" + array[i] + "']").prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td width="150">
      <label>First Checkbox</label>
    </td>
    <td class="super">
      <input type="checkbox" name="txtSup" value="First Checkbox">
    </td>
    <td width="180">
      <label>Second Checkbox</label>
    </td>
    <td class="super">
      <input type="checkbox" name="txtSup" value="Second Checkbox">
    </td>
    <td width="150">
      <label>Third Checkbox</label>
    </td>
    <td class="super">
      <input type="checkbox" name="txtSup" value="Third Checkbox">
    </td>
    <td width="130">
      <label>Fourth Checkbox</label>
    </td>
    <td class="super">
      <input type="checkbox" name="txtSup" value="Fourth Checkbox">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Given the first two issues I don't see how your code works at all, regardless of server.

Comment: why it is not your above code is not working on my question I have copied the same.